# How to check if user is already logged into instagram

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I am currently using node.js, express, and mongodb for an instagram app. I have found that many times I would like to know whether or not a user is already logged into instagram (be it through my app via the instagram-node authentication or through instagram's actual website).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please let me know if any additional information would help in answering this question

Comment: "through my app via the instagram-node authentication or through instagram's actual website" It's not the same

Comment: I would like to know once a user has logged in through the Instagram api which is in my app. Does that clarify the question?

Comment: It bothers me that someone would bother commenting on an unanswered question only to criticize. At least provide some input. Either way, I was able to find another question that is along the same lines of what I had in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378345/switch-user-or-re-authenticate-with-instagram

Comment: I simply cannot understand your needs and you didn't post any code. How can I help you? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using passport to solve this problem. Passport conveniently takes care of handling instagram authorization and they even include an example app to see how it all works. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-instagram/blob/master/examples/login/app.js

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login')
}
```

Is especially useful since it can be placed at the top of your routing file and all the routes underneath it will first check to see if the user is authenticated.